# Not able to pass Bearer token in headers of a GET request in Golang

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

I am using oauth2 to access a third party API. I can get the access token alright, but when I try to call the API by passing the bearer token in the request headers it gives me 401 (Unauthorized) error.  Although it works well when I try to do it via POSTMAN by passing headers as  (Authorization: Bearer ). But it does not work using go.

Here is the code sample.

```
url := "http://api.kounta.com/v1/companies/me.json"

var bearer = "Bearer " + <ACCESS TOKEN HERE>
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Add("authorization", bearer)

client := urlfetch.Client(context)

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
writer.Write([]byte(body)) // Gives 401 Unauthorized error, though same works using POSTMAN
```

Comment: Have you tried to `Set()` the header instead of `Add()`ing it? [`Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Add) appends values to the existing header, whereas [`Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Set) will overwrite existing headers. Also according to the RFCs headers fields are case-insensitive, but some languages (i.e. PHP) don't know about that and will be looking for `Authorization`...

Comment: @Havelock: the go textproto package canonicalizes all headers when you set them.

Comment: @TahirRauf: have you looked at the headers to see how they are being sent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Actually the problem was two way.

1) The API end point was doing a redirect (302), which was causing a 302 response and then the other API was being called.

2) GO by default does not forward the headers, thus my bearer token was being lost in the middle.

FIX:

I had to override the client's CheckRedirect function and manually pass the headers to the new request.

```
client.CheckRedirect = checkRedirectFunc
```

Here is how I forwarded the headers manually.

```
func checkRedirectFunc(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", via[0].Header.Get("Authorization"))
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when sending a request to CloudFront + ElasticBeanstalk the error was resolved by placing this function to handle the redirection