# Go test to validate connect2id gives "invalid_client" error

Tags: go, idp, go-testing, connect2id

I'm trying to validate the [Connect2id](https://connect2id.com/) set up with Go test and I'm getting following error.

```
"Client authentication failed: Missing client authentication","error":"invalid_client"
```

The full scenario output is look like below.

```
Feature: Test Identity Provider

  Scenario:                                                             # features/idp.feature:3
    Given identity provider 'hf1-idp.json'                               # main_test.go:72 -> *Scaffold
    When I request an access token as 'cc_test'                          # main_test.go:83 -> *Scaffold
    oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {"error_description":"Client authentication failed: Missing client authentication","error":"invalid_client"}
    Then the token should have a claim 'scope'                           # main_test.go:92 -> *Scaffold
    And the token should have a claim 'sub' with value 'dips-mra'        # main_test.go:106 -> *Scaffold
    And the token should have a claim 'hso:userid' with value 'dips-mra' # main_test.go:106 -> *Scaffold
```

My *hf1-idp.json* file look like below.

```
{
  "kind": "PING",
  "issuer": "https://my.issuer.com/c2id",
  "insecure": true,
  "clients": {
    "cc_test": {
      "flow": "clientcredentials",
      "id": "clientId",
      "secret": "",
      "scopes": ["openid", "solr"],
      "values": {
          "resource": ["https://my.solrnode1.com/solr/", "https://my.solrnode2.com/solr/"]
      }
    },
```

Connect2id works fine in the set up environment. As an example I get expected result when I run following Curl command with correct values

```
curl -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST https://my.issuer.com/c2id/direct-authz/rest/v2 \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ztucBearerToken" \
        -d '{
  "sub_session" : { "sub" : "alice" },
  "client_id"   : "clientId",
  "scope"       : [ "openid", "solr" ],
  "claims"      : [ "name", "email", "email_verified", "access_token:hso:subject:system", "access_token:hso:subject:id", "access_token:hso:subject:name", "access_token:hso:subject:role:system", "access_token:hso:subject:role:id", "access_token:hso:subject:role:name", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:system", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:id", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:name", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:child-organization:system", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:child-organization:id", "access_token:hso:subject:organization:child-organization:name", "access_token:hso:purpose:system", "access_token:hso:purpose:id", "access_token:hso:purpose:description", "access_token:hso:resource:system", "access_token:hso:resource:id" ]
}'
```

Updated with following codes

main_test.go

```
func (sc *Scaffold) readIdentityProvider(filename string) error {
    idp, err := idp.ReadIdentityProvider(context.Background(), "testdata/"+filename)

// More code goes here
}
```

provider.go

```
func ReadIdentityProvider(ctx context.Context, filename string) (*IdentityProvider, error) {
    config, err := readIdentityProvider(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return NewIdentityProvider(ctx, config)
}

func NewIdentityProvider(ctx context.Context, config *Config) (*IdentityProvider, error) {
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, oauth2.HTTPClient, &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: config.Insecure,
            },
        },
    })
    provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, config.Issuer)

// More code goes here
}
```

oidc.go

```
func NewProvider(ctx context.Context, issuer string) (*Provider, error) {
    wellKnown := strings.TrimSuffix(issuer, "/") + "/direct-authz/rest/v2"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", wellKnown, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    resp, err := doRequest(ctx, req)    // Herer I get 401 Unauthorized
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
// More code goes here
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code from `main_test.go`?
The error `invalid_client`refers usually to a wrong/missing `client_id` or `client_secret`

Comment: @SchCh updated the question with related Go code

Comment: Could you also include any relevant logs from tomcat/logs/c2id-server.log ?

Comment: @VladimirDzhuvinov connect2id runs inside a docker container and when I checked inside the container, the file content is empty. But I have `docker logs container_id` output, which is huge. Is there any specific thing that I need to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Bearer token in the request. (https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/integration/direct-authz#error-401)
When you curl you use the -H parameter to add the Authorization Bearer token
`-H "Authorization: Bearer ztucBearerToken"`

You need to do the same in your Go application.

```
func NewProvider(ctx context.Context, issuer string) (*Provider, error) {
    wellKnown := strings.TrimSuffix(issuer, "/") + "/direct-authz/rest/v2"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", wellKnown, nil)

    bearer := "Bearer ztucBearerToken"
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    resp, err := doRequest(ctx, req)    // Herer I get 401 Unauthorized
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
// More code goes here
}
```

***Some supportive facts***

Similar SO discussion goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452148/how-can-i-make-a-request-with-a-bearer-token-in-go).

To get rid of the

> 400 Bad Request: {"error_description":"Bad request: Invalid JSON:
>   Unexpected token  at position 0.","error":"invalid_request"}

what you have to do is pass necessary request body like below.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", wellKnown, bytes.NewBuffer(bytesRepresentation))
```

Fore more info visit, Golang documentation related to [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

Comment: Ended up with this error `400 Bad Request: {"error_description":"Bad request: Invalid JSON: Unexpected token  at position 0.","error":"invalid_request"}`